# Move columns from one row to another existing row in jquery

Tags: jquery

Find below my table structure.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make it appear like

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>            
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Move 3 columns from the first row and insert into a second existing row using JQuery. Please suggest to iteratively do this when the number of columns in a row exceeds 3, then insert into a new existing row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

---

```
$("tbody td:nth-child(3n)")
    .css("background-color", "lightblue")
    .after("myPointer");


$("tbody").each(function(){

    /* update new TR's based on "myPointer" */
    var new_html = $(this).html().replace(/myPointer/g, "</tr><tr>");
    $(this).html(new_html);



    /* bonus - remove empty TR's */

    $("tr", this).each(function(){
    // loop through all "tr" in "this"-"tbody" scope

        if ($("td", this).length == 0) {
        // if there are zero "td" in "this"-"tr" scope

            $(this).remove();
            // then remove "$(this)"-"tr"

        }

    });


});
```

---

[Jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/peuq142h/7)

Comment: Hi, can you please help to include this in a web page where there are many tables and not just this. I want this to be applied to one table. But when I use this in my current page, myPointer gets appended everywhere and it changes the complete html.

Comment: @Anitha. I've updated to match your criteria. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you it worked.. is it possible to include the table name in $("td:nth-child(3n)") this line of code too.

Comment: Hi, is there a way I can modify the code when there is an input like <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>G</td>
            <td>H</td>
            <td>I</td>     
            <td>J</td>
            <td>K</td>
            <td>L</td>
            <td>M</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

Comment: and want the output as <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>G</td>
            <td>H</td>
            <td>I</td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>J</td>
            <td>K</td>
            <td>L</td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
            <td>M</td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

Comment: Its working with in JSFiddle. But when used same in my code it doesn't work. It iteratively doesn't pull. Can you please mention as what $(this) represents here?

Comment: Yes got it. the problem i had is in my table structure. I have a </TD> in my structure that doesn't have the corresponding <TD>. So "myPointer" is getting placed in different locations. Is there a way to delete the unmatched tags in the entire structure.

Comment: @Anitha. Are you saying the html isn't well-formed? If so, you will need to fix it yourself, javascript/jquery aren't there to fix html.

Answer (score 2):

Nice question. Let's try this way:

```
$(function () {
  // Create two temp rows.
  a = $("<tr />");
  b = $("<tr />");
  // Find our TR and loop in all the TDs.
  $("tr").first().find("td").each(function () {
    if (a.find("td").length < 3)
      a.append(this);
    else
      b.append(this);
  });
  c = $("tr").first().closest("tbody");
  $("tr").first().remove();
  $("tbody").append(a);
  $("tbody").append(b);
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  // Create two temp rows.
  a = $("<tr />");
  b = $("<tr />");
  // 
  $("tr").first().find("td").each(function () {
    if (a.find("td").length < 3)
      a.append(this);
    else
      b.append(this);
  });
  c = $("tr").first().closest("tbody");
  $("tr").first().remove();
  $("tbody").append(a);
  $("tbody").append(b);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>E</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see any change after implementing this javascript. It doesn't move the columns to the existing row.

Comment: @Anitha Were you able to run the snippet?

Comment: Thanks Praveen. Am able to run the snippet but if the number of columns in the first row exceeds 6. It needs to split and insert into 2 other rows which didn't work.

Comment: @Anitha Did the snippet give you the intended result, if so, we can amend the snippet further to make it work.

Comment: @Anitha It will be iterating for sure. That's the reason for `.each()`. What's the problem now, or you found any other solution?

Comment: In this input <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>E</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>G</td>
      <td>H</td>
      <td>I</td>
      <td>J</td>  
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table> it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="btnClick">Format</button>

   $("#btnClick").click(function () {
    $('table tbody tr').each(function(index,options)
    {
        $(this).find('td').each(function(index1,options1)
        {
           if(index1 > 2)
           {
              $('table tbody tr').eq(index+1).append($(this));         
           }
        });        

    });
});
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/zo3hh2ye/15/

Comment: This works only for incrementing the first row but not for all rows iteratively.